# Does DOJO offers an alternative to "extension points" for custom widgets?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am designing a custom widget using DIJIT and DOJO 1.10.

Basically my custom widget needs to have some behavior like a button, so when user click on it something can happen. I need to make sure other developers can add custom code when `onClick` it is fired on that widget.

After [reading this guide](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html) I understood that my custom widget should implement **extension points**. I have notice in the source code in DIJIT for Button.js and I see they using a special mixin called `dijit._OnDijitClickMixin`.

Below code for my widget, so far it works fine, but I would like to know:

- Is extension point the right way? Does a better alternative exists?
- Reading at the documentation I see the following code.

---

```
_onButtonClick: function( /*Event*/ e){
  ... // Trust me, _onClick calls this._onClick
},
_onClick: function( /*Event*/ e){
  ...
  return this.onClick(e);
},
onClick: { // nothing here: the extension point!

}
```

My custom widget does not implement any of these functions and seems working fine.

- Shall I include these functions? What is the reason for that?

### Widget

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/_WidgetBase',
    'dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin',
    'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
    'dojo/text!./templates/template.html'
], function (
    declare,
    _WidgetBase,
    _OnDijitClickMixin,
    _TemplatedMixin,
    template
    ) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _OnDijitClickMixin], {
        templateString: template
    });
});
```

### HTML template

```
<div data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:onClick"> </div>
```

### Initialize the widget

```
    this._iconPage = new IconPages({
        id: 'iconPage',
        onClick: function () {
            //do smt
        }.bind(this)
    }).placeAt('content');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine as the onClick method is meant to be overwritten to hook into events. What you can also do is hook into your IconPages "click" event using [dojo/on](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html) by doing something like this:

```
on(this._iconPage, "click", /*function here*/);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you think including dijit._OnDijitClickMixin define the class is really necessary? I have tried without and custom widget works also fine. Please let me know your toughs. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm you should but there may be something else at work here if it's working. If all you're really trying to do is extend a button though, you can actually just simply extend the dijit/form/Button class itself and get all of it's other features.